# Unable to resolve valid table in PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

I'm getting `unable to resolve table` errors appear in php files containing SQL querying valid tables.

[image]

If I <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> over the query, then I get expected results in the DB console, and if I expand the database in the DB explorer tab then I can see the tables.

It's not affecting code execution, but it's annoying because it catches my eye when writing code, and it masks real SQL errors.

I've tried refreshing the database connection, and I've verified that the php tab is connecting to the correct database.

Comment: 1) Try re-creating DB connection from scratch (delete that one and create again); 2) Make sure that one of the databases is selected as "default" (basically -- a tick in "resolve unqualified references" column for that DB). Ideally work with db logins that can see only 1 DB; 3) Maybe it conflicts with another DB-oriented plugin (try with ALL non-bundled plugins disabled); 4) And please always state exact IDE version used

Comment: @LazyOne - Deleting and recreating the datasource worked, thanks.  I'll mark it accepted if you copy the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try re-creating DB connection from scratch (delete existing one and create it again).

---

Thinking of possible reasons ... I can think of this scenario:

- working with project in current stable version (currently 2016.1.x);
- trying EAP build for next version (2016.2 at this moment) on this project and make some DB-related changes there (even simple syncing DB);
- going back to stable version (2016.1.x) .. and because new version uses newer file format/versioning for DB-related data (cached DB structure etc) IDE may start ignoring "unknown/newer" format for such data and instead of throwing appropriate warning it just "silently" throwing "unresolved table" message.

No other ideas.

Comment: For me it helped going to the datasource properties and unchecking `Current Schema` leaving only the correct database checked. Otherwise it would try to resolve everything from the `information_schema` database.

Comment: @SteenSchütt This suggest me that you may not have selected the DB in Connection settings... At very least that's my thoughts on possible reason for such behaviour.

Comment: I had selected both `Current Schema` and the database I wanted. I suppose `information_schema` was the current, but I'm just pointing it out as an additional debugging step.

Answer (score 47):

In 2017.2 I had to go to

> *Settings > Languages & Frameworks > SQL Resolution Scopes*

and add my project and database link in there to get it right again.

Comment: Me too. It was set to all databases and I had to switch it to the specific database I was using for this project. SQL Server and PHPStorm 2017.2.

Comment: also check 'Settings > Languages & Frameworks > SQL Dialects' , need to select the db you use.

Answer (score 14):

I was getting what OP was getting, and the problem was my DB Server was MariaDB and i had MySQL selected as the SQL Dialect.

See File > Settings:  Languages & Frameworks > SQL Dialects.

Comment: Thanks, that was driving me nuts! It was my issue as well and every other answer didn't do anything

Answer (score 12):

Faulty error pollution DRIVES ME NUTS TOO!

If I start having SQL resolution issues, I will check my resolution scopes (settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> SQL Resolution Scopes).

Generally I have the most issues when my project mapping is set to 'All Data Sources' by default.

The following steps always fixes it for me:

- Click the Project Mapping Dropdown
- Uncheck the global 'All Data Sources' setting (required to make other selection available)
- Click the drop down arrow for your Database connection
- Check 'All Schemas' (Or Specific Tables)
- Click OK to close the settings window

Your false resolution errors should disappear after the next parse cycle.

You aren't limited to applying the above steps to just one DB connection, you can do it for all connections in your project.

---

Sometimes adding a custom resolution scope will work as well, but it is hit or miss for me.

- Click the plus sign (top right)
- Select the file you are working on and hit 'OK'
- Select the 'Resolution Scope' column
- Deselect 'all data sources'
- Select the specific DB resources you want

Reconnecting to the DB never works for me.

Specifying the table works well... but it can become very cumbersome as the project grows.

---

I have also run into an additional situation where PHPStorm would only resolve some of my queries, no matter what scope resolution settings I used. However, after I attached a console to my file, they resolved just fine.
(Search for 'Attach Console' in Help | Find Action. You can also add it to a 'Quick List' or Keymap it.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about unchecking "All Data Sources". That really helped.

Answer (score 5):

Although this answer is specifically for phpstorm, I had this same issue in IntelliJ and none of the above fixes worked for me. I had my scope added, everything was active. I could query the database in the console window perfectly fine, and I was totally stumped.

Eventually, I noticed some text in the database panel that said `0 of 4` in tiny text. It looked like this:

[image: Database panel showing the 0 of 4 message]

Upon clicking on the `0 of 4` text, I discovered there were no schemas added to the connection, even though a default database was set upon making the connection originally. Going to that page allows you to add schemas. Be sure to either select "All schemas", "Current schema", or the specific database that you want to use with your connection.

Comment: Wow, I'm wondering why this is the default behaviour, this caused my issue too. Probably especially applicable when having multiple databases?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that introspecting large databases is a relatively expensive operation. Essentially, connection != introspection. When you think about it like that, it honestly makes more sense to have it the way it is.

Answer (score 5):

Changed dialect to MariaDB on global and project level.

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me! Thank you so much! It drove me nuts.

Answer (score 4):

Adding database name before the table name worked in my case.

For instance, instead of writing `SELECT * FROM Client`, put `SELECT * FROM database.Client`.

Answer (score 4):

To dismiss this error in PHPStorm versions before 2017 which have no `SQL Resolution Scopes` option:

1. Go to **File**
2. Go to **Settings**...
3. Go to **Editor** and then **Inspections**
4. In **SQL chapter** uncheck **Unresolved reference**
5. Click **Apply** and then **OK**

Answer (score 2):

I will add another answer, because for me, it was a completely different (embarrassing) cause:

I somehow forgot to add the **database name** in the **data sources general settings** (where you also set the host, user and password).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have clicked the right button in the SQLScript and change the Dialect to "Generic SQL". It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check the `Schemas` tab, and make sure you've added the database.

[image]

If the `unable to resolve table` error stills appears, there're two options to fix this:

1.You can edit the `properties` of the Data Source and add the name of `Database`, then you can see that `select * from table` works well.

[image]

2.On the other hand, you can also use sql like this `select * from database.table`. It works for me.

By the way, in many situations, autocomplete can be very useful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows:

1. <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + F10</kbd>
2. new query console
3. Write a selection query to the database, for example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email='$email' AND user_password='$password'
```

4. Enter your code page and click on the table name in the query
5. <kbd>ALT + ENTER</kbd>
6. run query in console
7. Select the console you created

Answer (score 0):

[PHPSTORM]I solved this problem by setting

> Languages&Features
> SQL Dialect

adding your current file into `path` and modify its `SQL Dialect` as a server you are using.
NOTICE!!!!! mine is MySQL but it is exactly `MySQL` **causing problems**, after switching into [`generic SQL`] **PROBLEM SOLVED**!!!